# Efficient way to connect to database (by performance)

Tags: database, java

I want to build a programm, which connects to a database. Inprinciple, my code works. I use "Hibernante-4.3.1" and a postgresql-driver "postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc41.jar".

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence" version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="******" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="******"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="******"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/*******"/>          
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>        
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

For localhost, it's okeyishly fast, but if I want to connect to a external server via internet, it takes about 30-60 seconds to establish the connection. Once it is initialised, all subsequent requests are executed fast enough, but the first call is taking way to long.

I could restructure the whole project as a WEB-Project and make a JBoss Datasource via JTA. That way, the connection is established before the programm starts and all would be fine. But I'd would like it a lot more to have if I didn't have to do that. What's the right way to connect like this?

Edit: Some more information: The line which takes the long time is:

```
javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("OneGramService");
```

Greetings,
Rhodarus

Comment: This seems to be a long way off-topic for us. I suspect you are aiming for the main StackOverflow site. Please confirm that and I'll migrate.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, that's why I found only tex-entries. Thanks for migrating.

Comment: Way too broad to answer

Comment: If you're connecting to a remote DB server, you're subject to the connection that your machine and the server have between each other.  There's not much in terms of code that could make it more efficient on an initial connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults` property to false.

Comment: Which network guys do you mean? The up/downstreams of both sides are ok, but the line of code doesn't seem to utilize the bandwidth. I added the line, which takes up the long time:

javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("OneGramService");

Comment: Did you try to set hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults property to false?
You can also try to set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to validate.

Comment: This! Thank you very very much, including:

<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"></property>

cut the init-time from 108 seconds to 6. I ran into problems with:

<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/> 
because it crashes with anything else than "create" or "update", but that's for another question. The big point is, that the jdbc metadata defaults were the cause of the time consuming trouble. Edit-update: changing from create to update did cut time from 30 seconds to 6.

Comment: ok then let me write it as an answer so people won't have to read a comment of font size 6.